# Let $p$ be a prime and $n>1$ an integer such that $n\mid p-1$ and $p\mid n^3-1$, then $4p-3$ is a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, intuition

> Let $p$ be a prime and $n>1$ an integer such that $n\mid p-1$ and $p\mid n^3-1$, then $4p-3$ is a perfect square.(*)

What I did:
Supose $p>4$
since $n<p$ then $\gcd(p,n-1)=1$ therefore $p$ divides $n^2+n+1$
so $n^2 \equiv -n-1 \mod p$
by Fermat's little theorem: 
$n^{p-1} -1 \equiv 0 \mod p$ this implies $1+n+n^2+...+n^{p-2} \equiv 0 \mod p$
so $p \equiv 1 \mod 3$. Now I'm stuck.

EDIT: in order to avoid ambiguity: Supose for a given prime number there is one natural number, $n$, greater than 1 such that:
$\begin{cases}
n \vert p-1\\ 
p \vert n^3-1
\end{cases}$ prove (*)

Comment: is this question is how to show $4p-3$ is a perfact square? then what is $n$?

Comment: yes, the question is to show that 4p-3 is a perfect square. I don't know what is $n$ but that's part of the problem. I only know there is such $n$ maybe one can find it

Comment: @MANMAID for example, for $p=7$ we can take $n=2$ and $4*7-3=25$ get it?

Comment: okk, yes... got it!!!

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t180f6h1449320s1_prove_that_4p3_is_a_perfect_square

Comment: @MANMAID  Good link.  more efficient solution than mine (posted below), but different enough so that I think I'll leave mine up for now.

Comment: ha ha, @lulu I just googled "4p-3 is a perfect square", since I could not understand what he was saying (if he wrote---- Let $p$ be a prime and $n>1$ an integer such that $n\mid p-1$ and $p\mid n^3-1$, then $4p-3$ is a perfect square. ) I would not even googled it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $$n\,|\,p-1\implies p-1=kn\implies p=kn+1$$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$

Similarly $$p\,|\,n^2+n+1\implies mp = n^2+n+1$$ for some $m\in \mathbb N$

It follows that $$n^2+n+1=m(kn+1)=mkn+m\implies n^2+(1-mk)n+(1-m)=0$$

Now, the roots of this quadratic must be integers, so the discriminant must be a perfect square.  It follows that there is some $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $$(1-mk)^2+4(1-m)=N^2$$

Case I:  $m=1$  In that case $$p=n^2+n+1\implies 4p-3=(2n+1)^2$$

Case II:  $m>1$.  In that case we easily see that $$4(m-1)≥2(mk-1)+1$$ But this quickly shows that $k=1$ which implies that $p=n+1$ which would imply that $n+1\,|\,n^2+n+1$ which is impossible.